# Which mysql library is supported in php hiphop?

Tags: php, mysql, hiphop

In regular php, there are multiple libraries for accessing mysql, such as mysql, mysqli, pdo and mysqlnd.

Which of these libraries are supported in php hiphop (https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/)?

Answer (score 1):

Hiphip for PHP is not library/module specific.  Built-in PHP modules are already written in C++ and compiled.  You can write your own by hand.  All that Hiphop for PHP does is automates that process for you.  Since the built in modules are already compiled, Hiphop for PHP just ignores them.  It has no bearing on what built-in libraries you can use in your code or what it works with.

The only place you may find issues with Hiphop for PHP is if you write closures or evals in your code.  As of the last time I checked, Hiphop for PHP could not handle them.  However, things may have changed since then.

**EDIT:**
Looks like interoperability with all built in functions was not fully implemented after all.  Documentation and use of Hiphop is pretty minimal (as in you've already found it).  You may just want to do some small tests to see if the libraries you want to use are supported.  Do post the results back up here so others can benefit!

Comment: According to the following, hiphop does not support all libraries bundled with standard php. For example, the postgresql library is not supported: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/issues/264

Comment: Interesting that's the first I've heard of there being an issue with the interoperability with other functions in PHP.  Looks like you've already found all the documentation that exists for Hiphop.  If you can download the source for other modules, you should be able to compile them the same way. :-/

Answer (score 0):

No php Hip-Hop does'nt support any of this libraries except **PDO**

I have also tried it but it did'nt work

For Further information please see below link:-

http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/10/hiphop-for-php-unimplemented-functions-and-features/